# Sums of solutions to $z^n-1 = 0$ that equal 0

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, vector-spaces

Consider the solutions of the equation $z^n - 1 = 0$, where $z$ is a complex number: ${z_1,z_2...z_n}$. What are ALL the possible sums $\sum_{i=1}^n a_iz_i$ over these n solutions, where $a_i$ are non-negative integers, that yield 0?

Comment: $a_i=1$ for all $i$

Comment: Yes, but I would like to know all possible sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are infinitely many such sets of solutions in general. For example, suppose n has k factors less than itself namely $d_1, d_2, \cdots d_k$. Now, choose k random numbers $b_1, b_2, \cdots b_k$. If we order the $z_i$s in order of their argument, then we can simply set $a_i = \sum_{d_j|i}{b_j}$. You can verify than for any selection of $b_i$s, this set of $a_i$s gives us a solution to $\sum{a_i}{z_i} = 0$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I suppose my main question is, are ALL solutions of the form you proposed?

Comment: Yes, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10911/english-reference-for-a-result-of-kronecker

Comment: Thank you very much for the link!

Answer (score 2):

Notice that
$$
z^n - 1 = (z-z_1)\cdots (z-z_m)
$$
If you develop this product, the term in front of $z^{n-1}$ is the sum of the roots $z_1+\dots+z_n$, which is zero, because $z^{n-1}$ is not present on the left hand side of the equation.

Also remember that the solutions of $z^n-1$ are the vertices of a regular $n$-agon, whose baricenter is the origin.

Comment: It is clear that the sum of the roots is 0 because they would form an n-gon, but I was interested in all possible sums.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $r_1, \cdots,r_n$ are the roots of the polynomial $a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0x^0$, then $$a_{n-q}=\sum_{\text{cyc}}r_{i_1}\cdots r_{i_q}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Wonder's answer, let $$a_i=\sum_{k=0}^{d_j-1}\enspace\sum_{i=k\pmod {d_j}}b_{jk}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My main question is, are ALL possible solutions of this form?